# Mysql reporting have_openssl disabled

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am running WAMP - the latest version with MySQL 5.6.17, setup all the certificates which all have RSA correct headers. This is the relevant section from my.ini:

```
    # The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
    [client]
    #password   = your_password
    port        = 3306
    socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
    ssl-ca      = D:/ssl/mysql/ca-cert.pem
    ssl-cert    = D:/ssl/mysql/client-cert.pem
    ssl-key     = D:/ssl/mysql/client-key.pem

    # Here follows entries for some specific programs

    # The MySQL server
    [wampmysqld]
    ssl-ca      = D:/ssl/mysql/ca-cert.pem
    ssl-cert    = D:/ssl/mysql/client-cert.pem
    ssl-key     = D:/ssl/mysql/client-key.pem
    port        = 3306
    socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I have started the process with:

```
 C:\apacheserver\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqld.exe --ssl-ca=D:/ssl/mysqlca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=D:/ssl/server-cert.pem --ssl-key=D:/ssl/server-key.pem
```

And when I run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%' I see:

```
    have_openssl    DISABLED    
    have_ssl    DISABLED
    ssl_ca      D:/ssl/mysqlca-cert.pem
    ssl_cert    D:/ssl/server-cert.pem
    ssl_key     D:/ssl/server-key.pem
```

So what on earth am I missing? I have users which are reporting SSL settings but SSL is still disabled.

Thanks
Antony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key here is that I was passing the wrong SSL paths when calling mysqld. What this also tells me is that MySQL uses both the command line settings and the conf file to create the SSL settings.